# Custom counter in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this code in a django template page

```
<select class="selectpicker datatable-column-control" multiple
{% for q_group in question_groups %}
    <optgroup label="{{ q_group.name }}">
    {% for q in  q_group.questions %}
        <option value="{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ q.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </optgroup>
{% endfor %}
```

I want a value for every option tag that increases in each iteration. If I have 10 option tags, then their values will be from 0 to 9. 
`forloop.counter0` does not fulfill my need as the inner loop counter initializes to 0 when outer loop finishes once.

Answer (score 7):

How about passing  a [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) object to the template?

Template:

```
<select class="selectpicker datatable-column-control" multiple>
{% for q_group in question_groups %}
    <optgroup label="{{ q_group.name }}">
    {% for q in  q_group.questions %}
        <option value="{{ counter }}">{{ q.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </optgroup>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

View:

```
import itertools
import functools

render(request, 'template.html', {
    question_groups: ...,
    counter: functools.partial(next, itertools.count()),
})
```

Comment: That's a great solution when you need the value of the counter change on a conditional basis inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving this post to provide solutions using only the template language.

If you know you only have one `{% for %}` in between the counter (as in example above), use [forloop.parentloop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#for). You can chain many of these together, but the number of loops separating the desired loop must be known, and using it becomes less desirable after a few (`forloop.parentloop.parentloop...`).

```
{% for foo in foos %}
  {% for bar in bars %} {# exactly one for loop between here #}
    {{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }} is the index of foo. 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you have an arbitrary number of for loops between the two (say in a template you can't control, or django-crispy-forms), save the loop variable with a [with statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% for foo in foos %}
  {% with foo_num=forloop.counter0 %}
    {% for bar in bars %} {# any number of for loops between #}
      {{ foo_num }} is the index of foo. 
    {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Falsetru's solution is a best fit for a counter that lacks a for loop, or one that keeps counting after one has ended. This feature isn't really possible with only the builtins, so the itertools from falsetru's answer is necessary.

```
{% for foo in foos %}
  {{ counter }} is the index of foo
{% endfor %}
{% for bar in bars %}
  {{ counter }} is the index of bar + len(foos)
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
{% for foo in foos %}
    {{ forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for